# Complete Vite build despite TypeScript errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I have a Vite/Vue/Typescript project that currently has a lot of TypeScript issues that can not be quickly resolved.

When I attempt to build, the build fails:

```
Found 20 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     3  src/App.vue:3
    17  src/stations.ts:7
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

How can I force the build to complete, in spite of the errors?

(I do at some point intend to resolve these issues, and I'm fine with them being reported as errors in the mean time - I just don't want the creation of a build to be blocked)

My dependencies are:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-pug": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-pug-plugin": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `scripts`:

```
"build-only": "vite build"
```

And then run the script as usual:

```
npm/pnpm/yarn run build-only
```